# useState and useContext in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, forms, use-state, tslint, use-context

With useState, I wanted to create an object that I will continue to fetch in the (probably far ^^) future.

The code is to act as a form that will be on several subpages, each subpage is to provide different data to the object, which will eventually be fetching into the database.

Theoretically, I was able to combine useState and useContext, unfortunately I get the error

> Type '{}' must have a '[Symbol.iterator] ()' method that returns an iterator.ts (2488)

formContext.ts

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from 'react';

export const FormContext = createContext({});

export const FormProvider: React.FC = props => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({ title: '' });
  return <FormContext.Provider value={[formData, setFormData]}>{props.children}</FormContext.Provider>;
};
```

ServiceBoxGenerator.ts

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';

//Component Import
import { ServiceBox } from './ServiceBox/ServiceBox';
import { ProcedureBox } from './ProcedureBox/ProcedureBox';
//Context Import
import { ServiceContext } from '../../App';
import { FormContext } from '../../utils/formContext';

export const ServiceBoxesGenerator: React.FC = () => {
  const { data } = useContext(ServiceContext);
  const dataArray = data;
  const [formData, setFormData] = useContext(FormContext);
  if (formData.title) {
    const searchedObject = dataArray.find(x => x.title === formData.title);
    const procedureObject = searchedObject?.services;
    return (
      <>
        {procedureObject?.map(data => {
          return <ProcedureBox key={data.id} icon={data.icon} title={data.title} description={data.description} price={data.price} />;
        })}
      </>
    );
  }
  return (
    <>
      {dataArray.map(data => {
        return (
          <div
            key={data.id}
            onClick={() => {
              setFormData({ title: data.title });
            }}
          >
            <ServiceBox key={data.id} icon={data.icon} title={data.title} serviceAmount={data.amount} />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: This is where my error is]

I am asking for help and a hint what I am doing wrong because I have no idea what I can change to make it work.

Or maybe someone has another way to create such an object, I don't insist on using useState with useContext.

Thank you very much in advance for all your help, have a nice day ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the type of `{}` in `createContext({})` does not match the type of `[formData, setFormData]`.

The easy way to remove this error is to specify the type of context like that:

```
export const FormContext = createContext<[{ title: string },React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<{
  title: string;
}>>]>({} as any);
```

Comment: For first i need to use /* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any */ in formContext.tsx.My second new problem is new error now in ServiceBoxesGenerator https://i.imgur.com/PWiCSfd.png. Do you know any other metod to state managing in TS?

Comment: @Błażej Bałtruszewicz: Could u show me one simple example in codesandbox or something, because it works in my code

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-jones-8m0zi?file=/src/utils/formContext.tsx When you click on button Book Appointment you will get that freaking error :(

Comment: @Błażej Bałtruszewicz: That was because the tag `<ServiceBoxesGenerator>` isn't being wrapped by `<FormProvider> `, you can wrap it in parent or parent of parent..and `formData`, `setFormData` will works.

Comment: `formData`, `setFormData` will be working, but seems like there are some problems in the section of `dataArray`

Comment: Thank you so much @zixiCat Have a nice day :)